# QGraphicsscene: How to implement selection (by rubber band) behavior of QGraphicsItems?

Tags: qt, selection, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

so I know there are quite a lot of similar questions on here but none really gets to the specific point I am interested in.

I want to implement custom selection behavior of a `QGraphicsItem`s (e.g. change its color on selection). Apparently this is handled by the items themselves so one needs to make an own class extending `QGraphicsItem`. There, I am really missing something, like an `onSelectionToggled` method (slot) that one could override. But I finally figured out that one has to override the `mousePressEvent` method (after all "selection" is just a more concrete term for the abstract concept of a left-click).

So if in this method I call:

```
  setPen( QPen( QColor( "orange" ) ) );
  update();
```

The color actually changes when I click a single item. 
But not when the selection happens via the rubber band of the scene. 
Since there is no `onSelectionToggled`, I imagined the scene would "simulate" a respective mouse event for the intersected items.

Since this is not the case, my question is: "How can I react to such a selection via rubber band?" Ideally in a "unified" way (no extra code for individual selection by mouse click).

Also, I wonder how I can prevent the dotted bounding rectangle to be drawn on selection. I don't want it and was hoping to get rid of it automatically when subclassing `QGraphicsItem`.

Comment: Not for the big question, but for the dotted rectangle, I am afraid you will have to reimplement `QStyle::drawPrimitive`...

Comment: @AlexisP. Seriously? Because QStyle is an abstract class with many derived classes which all can be used in QGraphicsScene::setStyle.To me this looks like I have to either sublclass all these classes, overriding the drawPrimitive method. Or I pick only one subclass of QStyle but then I loose the scene's ability to adapt to the style of e.g. KDE, Mac OS or Windows (for which QStyle is actually for, as far as I can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QGraphicsItem` class is the base class for all graphical items in a `QGraphicsScene`. It is the `QGraphicsScene` class that contains all the functionality for handling `QGraphicsItem` selection. If you catch the signal `QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged()` you should be able to find the selected items through

```
`QList<QGraphicsItem *> QGraphicsScene::selectedItems()`
```

you can then change the pen for those items and redraw.

Of course since you want the items to turn back to their original colour once they are unselected, perhaps a better approach is to iterate over all items (`QList<QGraphicsItem *> QGraphicsScene::items()`) and check their `isSelected()` state to change their pen into the appropriate colour.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. The iteration over all items and checking if they are selected individually was indeed the right approach for me (since I also wanted to handle "de-selection" events). In the spirit of the MVC pattern, I have put the code in a controller class that has a pointer to the QGraphicsscne (as the model) and the QGraphicsView (as the view). Still feels a little bit awkward as the Qt docu explicitly tells you to implement dynamic behavior in the items …